# Left-align math and also align by equal sign?

Tags: align

```
\begin{flalign*}
    &f(x) = -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x + 1.66&\\
         &= -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x + 1.66 + 0&\\
\end{flalign*}
```

Is it possible to left-align these two lines of math and also align the two lines by the equal signs?

[image]

Comment: Move the `&` in the first line to be just before the `=`. That is, use `f(x) &= -1.25x^{2} ...`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks. Would you like to add your solution as an answer?

Comment: You should also remove the `&` symbols at the ends of both lines.

Comment: @Mico: I think those are required to have them left-indented (not centered).

Comment: @PeterGrill - If the objective is indeed to left-align rather than center the equations, the OP is abusing the `flalign*` environment. The OP should specify the option `fleqn` while loading `mathtools` (or `amsmath`) -- and use `align*`, not `flalign*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To align at the `=`, you need to have the `&` to be just *before* the `=`:

[image]

##Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    f(x) &= -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x + 1.66     & \\
         &= -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x + 1.66 + 0 & \\
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `fl` in `flalign` and `flalign*` is short for "full length", *not* "flush left". Please see page 8 of the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) of the `amsmath` package for some use cases for `flalign`. (Aside: Just because `flalign` *can* be abused to force displayed equations to be typeset left-aligned doesn't mean that it's harmless to do so.)

If the objective is to typeset displayed equations left-aligned rather than centered, you really shouldn't be using `flalign`. Instead, load the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package with the option `fleqn` (short for "flush-left equations") and set the value of the `\mathindent` length variable to `0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{showframe} % optional

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x + 1.66 \\
         &= -1.25x^{2} + 1.5x + 1.66 + 0 % note: no '\\' at end of final line of 'align'
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```